# Import multi excel files

Tags: excel, ssis, etl

I'm trying to import multiple Excel files into a single data warehouse (DWH). The problem is that the Excel files are different from each other, and I want to handle errors after encountering one in the Excel component. Is it possible to redirect the error to another Excel component in order to process the second type of Excel files?

Thank you in advance.

I'm trying to import multiple Excel files into a single data warehouse (DWH).I get an error that I can't control.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is not enough info here, but in general you need a data flow for each type of file you want to import. The process is pretty much rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Cribbing from a previous answer...

You can't. An SSIS data flow is not a generic "anything to anything" data moving tool. You can dynamically switch the source/destination from A to Z as long as the schema is the same for the columns that are being mapped (extra columns in table Z? No problem).

The metadata for an SSIS package is set at design time aka when you're in the Visual Studio editor. When it's processing file 1, it works as the current worksheet matches the expected metadata. File 2, everything is "different" and boom, VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error is thrown.

For what you're describing just add a Data Flow for each workbook/worksheet
five tables, just add N data flows and be done with it. Dynamic is good, there's lots of things that can be done with dynamic sources and destinations but adding in the complexity with Excel and it's interpreted data types. Heck no.

I assume you've got a foreach file loop container (FELC) consuming files in a folder and it's assigning the current file name to an SSIS variable.

One option is to filter for just the "Sales" files and inside the FELC only have the Sales data flow. The enumerator skips the Shipping and Employee files so the incorrect metadata doesn't cause the package to blow up. Copy & Paste the pattern but change the file filter to Shipping and put the Shipping data flow inside there and finally, connect the FELC Sales to FELC Shipping. Lather, rinse, repeat until you've covered all your imports.

A different option is to have as the first item in your FELC an empty Task, like a Sequence Container (SEQC). The purpose of that sequence container is to serve as a decision point. Then put each Data Flow as an output path from the SEQC in a fan like manner. SEQC lights up and we want only the path to the correct Data Flow to light up so we need to double click the precedence constraint connector and change it from the default of `Constraint` to `Constraint and Expression`

The logic here is going to be some boolean (true/false) check on how the SSIS should determine which path to take. For debugging purposes, I would create an SSIS Variable for each path and initialize everything to false.

- runSales - Boolean - `FINDSTRING(@[User::CurrentFile], "SALES", 1)
- runShipping - Boolean - `FINDSTRING(@[User::CurrentFile], "SHIPPING", 1)

[FINDSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/findstring-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver16) is going to be a case sensitive check so you might need to wrap

Armed with a variable for each data flow you want to conditionally execute, plumb that variable into the Precedence Constraint Editor

[image]